# Casting void pointers in C

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers

Let's assume a data structure in C such as

```
struct node {
    void *value;
    struct node *next;
} *Node;
```

**Is there any chance of cast a void pointer to a specific type of value? If so, how to do it safely?**

Creating a main like this

```
int main (void) {
    Node n = create_node ();

    insert (n, 2);
    insert (n, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Or this

```
int main (void) {
    Node n = creade_node ();

    // any struct. e.g.:
    struct data d = create_data ();

    insert (n, d);

    return 0;
}
```

Makes compiler yell at me warnings like "expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type *some_type*. How can I solve this kind of warnings?

Stuff like this (cast directly)

```
insert (Node n, void *value) {
    struct data new_value = (struct data) value;
    ...
}
```

can be done?

In Java, e.g., I can safely check if some method argument (object) is instance of a specific type and then perform a cast, if appropriate. How could I do this in C?

### **Bottom line, is it possible to check if a void pointer (i.e., inside it) is of type *some_type* and if so, cast that value to *some_type*?**

Comment: You can't cast a pointer into a non-pointer. You could cast into a `struct data*` if it happens to point to such structure

Comment: Can you share `create_data()` and `create_node()` with us ?

Comment: In what you've presented, you declare a *variable* named `Node` as a pointer to `struct node`, then attempt to use the variable name as if it were a type name.

Comment: No, void *s have type information stripped from them and are not "type safe". That doesn't mean they are especially unsafe to use, but you need to know what type the pointer points to from some other source. A common use is to provide context information for callback functions.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean can you elaborate on that, giving an example?

Comment: minimise(double *x, int N, void *ptr, double (*function)(double *, int, void *)) - the function to minimise takes a context pointer. So we don't need any globals, the ptr is probably some terrain or something. We're finding the x values than minimise it by a gradient descent variant method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is an address. A structure is a bunch of data, of known size. Although you can cast a pointer to a structure to a `void *`, since both are addresses, you cannot cast a structure to a `void *`, since a structure is not an address. The only thing you can do is cast a **pointer to** a structure from a `void *` :

```
insert (Node n, void *value) {
    struct data* new_value = (struct data*) value;
    ...
}
```

> In Java, e.g., I can safely check if some method argument (object) is instance of a specific type and then perform a cast, if appropriate. How could I do this in C?

You can't. A `void*` is nothing more than an address. You have no way to know what this address points to, or even the size of the data you are pointing to.

Comment: "You can't."  Indeed.  Therefore, it's a bad idea to use a void pointer when you mean to convey something different from a pointer that could point to anything.

Comment: Ok, that answers. So, I am able to perform a cast as demonstrated by @Fabien but I can not guarantee the safety of that, correct? With that said, if I cast some void pointer to a pointer to some other struct (e.g. struct data *new_value), I must be sure that **value** is of that type of data I am casting, right (with no mechanism of guaranteeing it)?

Comment: You can use "C-style inheritance" by putting "parent" structure as a first element of a "child" structure. You can also have some kind of a "type" field in that structure to have a kind of "instance of" check. You just have to do that manually.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `void *`, you can use C's `intptr_t`, which is defined as an int large enough to store a pointer in it. So you can cast your pointers to int when storing there, and you can also store integers.